# keep the div in viewport after load

Tags: css, angular

[image]

I need a css where  bottom div should be sticked to bottom and when the data loads scroll should happen by sticking the  bottom box div

Div a is inside div b

The gab between div b and a
there are a lot of data loading which will effect the position of the  div b which will scroll down and will be out of view port
so when this data loads the div should stay sticky to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want :

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>some text</p>").appendTo(".wrap");
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;}

body, html, .wrap{
  height:100%;
}

body > .wrap{
  height:auto;
  min-height:100%;
}

.wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100px; 
}

.wrap p{
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.footer{
  background:#662e8c;
  margin-top:-100px;
  height:100px;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:180%;
  padding:0 10px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
}
.footer1 {
  margin-bottom:48px !important;
  background:red;
    height:100px;
  width:100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add content</button>
<div class="wrap">
    <p>some text</p>


</div>
<div class="footer">
    Sticky Footer
</div>

<div class="footer1">
    Sticky Footer1
</div>
<div>
    Sticky Footer2
</div>
<div>
    Sticky Footer3
</div><div>
    Sticky Footer4
</div>
```

Comment: @msd Why? I am do not know what you mean. Can you show Example in your question?

Comment: hey check this out [link]( http://jsfiddle.net/6zm3debs/2/) the sticky should stick to the bottom and as soon as you reach the footer .

Comment: @msd I see sticky is is stickied to the footer which is the end.

Comment: yes but  when you scroll up the sticky is not visible

Comment: @msd Because sticky is sticked to the bottom. How do you want to show stick be showed? Do you want to float on scroll up and scroll down or What?

Comment: @msd This maybe what you want : https://jsfiddle.net/7Lk2w9ez/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232358/discussion-between-kevin-m-mansour-and-msd).